# Unexpected type Average

Tags: java

for some reason the command prompt keeps on asking me for input but I am placing a value on **line 12** (sum + one) = sum. If you guys could help me determine whats wrong with it that would be amazing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FunnyAverage {
   public static void main(String[] args){          
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("How many values to read? ");
   int top = in.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
   int one = in.nextInt();
   int number = 0;
   int sum = 0;
   (sum + one) = sum;

   while (number>top){
       while (one % 6 != 0&&one % 17 != 0) {
           System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
           one = in.nextInt(); 
           number++;
       }
   }

   if (sum/top != 0){
       System.out.print("Average: " + sum/top);
   }
   System.out.print("None Divisible");
   }
}
```

Comment: `(sum + one) = sum;` is not valid Java syntax. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: also, i believe `while(number` **`<`** `top)` was what you meant...

Comment: "If you guys could help me determine whats wrong with it that would be amazing." No, it wouldn't be amazing: in fact, it wouldn't be all that surprising at all :) :) :)

Comment: Calling a variable `one` is a strange choice. `one` is an acceptable name for a constant which is always equal to `1`, but a variable that according to your code could be any integer number should be called something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You meant:

```
sum = sum + one; // or sum += one;
```

By *command prompt*, I think you actually mean the compiler (which can write its error messages to the command prompt). The error message will be stating that the result of `(sum + one)` is not a variable.

See section [15.26. Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)  of the Java Language Specification, which states:

> The result of the first operand of an assignment operator must be a variable, or a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

```
(sum + one) = sum;
```

This is not possible. It should be `sum = (sum + one);` or `sum +=one;`