# Unsure what the issue is

Tags: java

I'm really new to this whole programming thing, and I'm trying to wrap my head around why the loop ends abruptly and does not continue to the final if statement. Can you guys help me figure out whats wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FunnyAverage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many values to read? ");
        int top = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
        int one = in.nextInt();
        int number = 1;
        int sum = 0;
        sum = sum + one;

        while (number <= top) {
            if (one % 6 != 0 && one % 17 != 0) {
                System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
                one = in.nextInt();
                number++;
            } else if (one % 6 == 0 && one % 17 == 0) {
                System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
                one = in.nextInt();
                number++;

            }

        }

        if (sum / top != 0) {
            System.out.print("Average: " + sum / top);
        }
        System.out.print("None Divisible");
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm, how does this relate to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744314/unexpected-type-average

Comment: If that one has been solved please consider to **accept** one of the answers (if one was helpful).

Comment: u mean this if() condtion -- if(sum / top != 0){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final if() condition executes if you give the right input values. I ran your code and gave the below inputs to execute the final if() statement.

```
How many values to read? 1
Enter Value: 1
Enter Value: 1
Average: 1None Divisible
```

I dont understand what are you trying in the code, but there are many things missing like i assume you want to capture the sum of the input numbers, but sum is not used in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you end up in the non-present `else` case (within the `while` loop). Consequently, `number` isn't increased and you are stuck in the `while` loop.

Try reading `one` within the `while` loop. This way the user will be prompted to enter a new number in each loop.

Otherwise you will be stuck in the `while` loop once the user enters a number that isn't conform with your checks.